# CSS animation works in Safari, but not in the Firefox and Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

I'm using [`animate.css`](http://daneden.me/animate/) to animate some elements in the page. There is a plugin for JQuery that helps you to use it easily, [`animateCSS.js`](https://github.com/craigmdennis/animateCSS)  (from GitHub). The problem is that the animations works in Safari, but not in the Firefox and Chrome, for example, I made a selector invisible:

```
#top{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

And this JQuery script fade it in:

```
$('#top').animateCSS('fadeInDown', 400);
```

After 400ms it become visible, but without animation!

It's online here http://ashraafi.com/index.html

Comment: When opening the console in Firebug I'm getting: `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://ashraafi.com/fonts/bbc-nassim-regular.woff"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange, it looks like the author left a part in his plugin code that shouldn't be there - at least it's not documented anywhere that it should be there.

Remove lines 63-67 of the pluign:

```
        if (!$("html").hasClass("csstransforms")) {

            onEnd();

        }
```

That was causing the animation to stop immediately. Why it worked in Safari I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I made sample: http://jsfiddle.net/QkCq2/ works in Chrome
HTML:

```
<div class="animated fadeInDown" style="background-color:green;">
<pre>


</pre>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
       -moz-animation-duration: 2s;
        -ms-animation-duration: 2s;
         -o-animation-duration: 2s;
            animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
       -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
        -ms-animation-fill-mode: both;
         -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
            animation-fill-mode: both;
}


.fadeInDown{
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -moz-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -ms-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    -o-animation-name: fadeInDown;
    animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```